# Populating objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java

not expecting anyone to write the whole code for this but any hints and tips will be appreciated.
Here's the problem:

> `In main()`, instantiate 60 BankAccount objects,
>       using random numbers for account numbers (8 digits, integer!),
>       3 distinct sort codes (form: xx-xx-xx),
>       and random numbers for balances (type: double!).
>       Your program must use the first sort code for the first 20 accounts,
>       the second sort code for the next 20, and the third sort code
>       for the third group of accounts.
>
> Store the BankAccount objects in an ArrayList.
>       When the list is complete, it must contain 60 BankAccount objects.

So far i have:

```
public class BankAccount {  
    int accountNum = 0;
    String sortCode = "";
    double balance = 0;

    public BankAccount(int accountNum, String sortCode, double balance){ 
        this.accountNum = accountNum;
        this.sortCode = sortCode;
        this.balance = balance;       
    }

    public static void display(int accountNum, String sortCode, double balance){  
        System.out.print(accountNum + sortCode + balance);
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

        BankAccount[] object = new BankAccount[60];

    }
}
```

Comment: `new BackAccount[60]` creates an array object but does not create any `BankAccount` objects.  You will have to use a loop (or more than one loop) to create each `BankAccount` object.  That's the only tip I think you should get, because it's something that confuses a lot of new Java programmers.  But for the rest of it, you'll have to try it yourself.

Comment: So for starters...`BankAccount[]` isn't an `ArrayList`.

Comment: What exactly is your question.  You've posted a homework assignment & some code...but SO is for asking specific questions.  Is that something in particular you don't understand, or an error that you can't figure out?  We need some more info here, because right now your question is too broad.

Comment: I'm stuck onhow to fill the BankAccount object with random values for the account numbers, sort codes and balances.

Comment: Take a look at the JavaDocs for [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
   for(int i=0; i < objects.length; i++){
        int accountNum = (int) random(8);
        String sortCode = (int) random(2) + "-" + (int) random(2) + "-" + (int) random(2);
        double balance = randomBetween(0, 100000);

        objects[i] = new BankAccount(accountNum, sortCode, balance);
    }
```

with the methods

```
public static double random(int numDigits){
  return randomBetween(0, Math.pow(10, numDigits) -1);
}

public static double randomBetween(double min, double max){
  return (Math.random() * (max-min)) + min;
}
```

Comment: also, that's an array, not an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating an ArrayList. What you are creating is a 1 dimensional array. ArrayList declarations are very similar to declaring arrays though, just a few differences. Instead of doing this: `BankAccount[] object = new BankAccount[60];` Do this for ArrayLists: `ArrayList <Integer> Account = new ArrayList <Integer>(60);` (assuming Account is an Integer)